# Avoid multiple data with same value when display list

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a map with data like below

```
Map map = {{'data1': 500}, {'data2': 200}, {'data3': 750}, {'data4': 200}}
```

and then i display it using MapEntry

```
for (MapEntry<String, num> value in mapList.entries)
Column(children: <Widget>[
   Text(value.key),
   Text(value.value)
]
```

How do i display it sorting according to value by ascending and also avoid displaying multiple data with the same value

example output

```
data2 / data4
200
data1
500
data3
750
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would properly use a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) and switch the key and value. Something like this:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final list = [
    {'data1': 500},
    {'data2': 200},
    {'data3': 750},
    {'data4': 200}
  ];

  final sortedMap = SplayTreeMap<int, List<String>>();

  for (final entry in list) {
    sortedMap
        .putIfAbsent(entry.entries.first.value, () => [])
        .add(entry.entries.first.key);
  }

  for (final entry in sortedMap.entries) {
    print('${entry.value.join(' / ')}');
    print(entry.key);
  }

  // data2 / data4
  // 200
  // data1
  // 500
  // data3
  // 750
}
```

The `SplayTreeMap` will automatically sort the `key` values in the map so it makes sense to use your int-number here as the key and then save a `List<String>` of your keys which have the same numeric value.